# In Enterprise grid slack, how do I send message using slack bot to a specific user in a workspace only if he/she also belongs in the other workspace?

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api, slack-bolt

In the Enterprise grid slack, if the same user is present in all the workspaces, their user_id is the same across all the workspaces. I am using the `chat.postMessage` slack API to send the message to the user belonging to a workspace. However, since the user_id is the same across all the workspaces, this message is also being sent to the user in other workspaces even after the access_token is different.

Comment: Unfortunately, DMs in Enterprise Grid organizations are universal (meaning, DMs do not belong to a specific workspace). So, you cannot force the workspace to use for notifications and which workspace to use for accessing the DM message.